# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities while reading s3 Data with spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I would like to run a simple spark job on my local dev machine (through Intellij) reading data from Amazon s3.

my *build.sbt* file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.407",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.1.1"
)
```

my code snippet:

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("test")
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark
    .sparkContext
    .hadoopConfiguration
    .set("fs.s3n.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")

  val schema_p = ...

  val df = spark
    .read
    .schema(schema_p)
    .parquet("s3a:///...")
```

And I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2058)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2593)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:354)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet(DataFrameReader.scala:606)
    at Test$.delayedEndpoint$Test$1(Test.scala:27)
    at Test$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:4)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at Test$.main(Test.scala:4)
    at Test.main(Test.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.StreamCapabilities
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 41 more
```

When replacing `s3a:///` to `s3:///` I get another error: `No FileSystem for scheme: s3`

As I am new to AWS, I do not know if I should user `s3:///`, `s3a:///` or `s3n:///`. I have already setup my AWS credentials with aws-cli.

I have not any Spark installation on my machine.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would start by looking at [the S3A troubleshooting docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#Classpath_Setup)

> Do not attempt to “drop in” a newer version of the AWS SDK than that which the Hadoop version was built with Whatever problem you have, changing the AWS SDK version will not fix things, only change the stack traces you see.

whatever version of the hadoop- JARs you have on your local spark installation, you need to have *exactly* the same version of `hadoop-aws`, and exactly the same version of the aws SDK which hadoop-aws was built with. Try [mvnrepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) for the details.

Comment: @ogen what is the right settings that worked for you finally? I searched Maven repo and am using com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.217,
  org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.1, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:3.1.1, but it is not working.

Comment: According to Maven's repository,  org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.1.1 depends on com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.271 and not com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.217, I think you made a typo. Hope this will solve your problem!

Comment: Note spark version in hadoop is under `org.apache.hadoop` dependency in the dependency tree, set the `hadoop-aws` dependency to this value.

Comment: This is exactly the solution. If you are using in your local system (pyspark installed through pip install), copying the correct 'hadoop-aws' and 'aws-java-sdk-bundle' .jar files under 'jar' folder of local pyspark installation should resolve this issue.

Comment: I am using spark `3.1.1`, with hadoop-aws `3.1.1` and aws-java-sdk-bundle`1.11.271` still getting same error. Anything I am missing ?

Comment: Okay, my mistake, I was looking at spark version instead of hadoop version. Its working now.

Answer (score 13):

For me, it got solved by adding the following dependency in pom.xml besides the above:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure about this since Spark doesn't use Hadoop 3.1.1 jars

Answer (score 1):

In my case I fixed it choosing correct dependency versions:

```
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.2.1",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.2.1"
```